# How to remove recommendation buttons on youtube?

Tags: youtube

I am getting recommendations in the form of buttons on youtube. How can I disable this?
Please see the image
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzjZn.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a native way to do it. However, if you have or are willing to download a style editor, you can remove it with this code:

```
.ytd-feed-filter-chip-bar-renderer{ display: none!important;}
```

Or to remove the entire header which includes the padding you can use

```
#primary > ytd-rich-grid-renderer > #header { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: This leaves padding where it was, if you disable `header` it'll be all of it but I have no idea how to do that. Ideas? *Edit:* apparently `:has` has been around since 2009 and still isn't supported nice.